# can two kubernetes volumes mount to the same place

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm pretty new to Kubernetes, trying to figure it out.   I haven't been able to google this answer tho, so I'm stumped.   Can Kubernetes mount two secrets to the same path? say given the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx-deployment
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: v1
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: nginxlocal
        hostPath:
          path: /srv/docker/nginx
      - name: requestcert
        secret:
          secretName: requests-certificate
      - name: mysitecert
        secret:
          secretName: mysitecert
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:mainline-alpine # Use 1.15.0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginxlocal
          subPath: config/nginx.conf
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - name: requestcert
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
        - name: mysitecert
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
        - name: nginxlocal
          subPath: logs
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/logs
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
```

would it be possible to mount both SSL certs to the same directory (/etc/nginx/ssl/*)?

If not, can storing the TLS cert+key as "Opaque" instead of kubernetes.io/tls type work?  I tried to combine both certs+keys into one secret of tls type, but kubernetes expected it to be called tls.crt and tls.key, so I had to split it into two secret files. if they could be done as opaque, i think I could remove the two secret values and just use the one opaque entry.

Thanks!

Comment: "A `projected` volume maps several existing volume sources into the same directory." Check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#projected and https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-projected-volume-storage/

Answer (score 6):

> would it be possible to mount both SSL certs to the same directory (/etc/nginx/ssl/*)?

No, because (at least when using a docker runtime) it uses volume mounts, which behave exactly the same as `mount -t ext4 /dev/something /path/something` in that `/path/something` will be last-one-wins.

However, you have an only mildly smelly work-around available to you: mount secret `requestcert` as `/etc/nginx/.reqcert` (or similar), mount secret `mysitecert` as `/etc/nginx/.sitecert`, then supersede the `entrypoint` of the image and copy the files into place before delegating down to the actual entrypoint:

```
containers:
- name: nginx
  image: etc etc
  command:
  - bash
  - -c
  - |
    mkdir -p /etc/nginx/ssl
    cp /etc/nginx/.*cert/* /etc/nginx/ssl/
    # or whatever initialization you'd like

    # then whatever the entrypoint is for your image
    /usr/local/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Or, if that doesn't seem like a good idea, you can leverage a disposable, Pod-specific directory in combination with `initContainers:`:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  # all the rest of them, as you had them
  - name: temp-config
    emptyDir: {}
  initContainers:
  - name: setup-config
    image: busybox  # or whatever
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
       # "stage" all the config files, including certs
       # into /nginx-config which will evaporate on Pod destruction
    volumeMounts:
    - name: temp-config
      mountPath: /nginx-config
    # and the rest

  containers:
  - name: nginx
    # ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: temp-config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx
```

They differ in complexity based on whether you want to have to deal with keeping track of the upstream image's entrypoint command, versus leaving the upstream image untouched, but expending a lot more initialization energy